# Out of Memory Error-Heap when storing parquet files using Flink Table API (Flink version-1.12.0) in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-table-api

Hope you are doing well. We are currently using Flink Table API (Flink Version-1.12.0) to stream data from Kafka and store it in Google Cloud Storage. The file format we are using to store data is Parquet. Initially the Flink job worked perfectly fine and we were able to stream data and store it successfully in Google Cloud Storage. But what we noticed is, once we increase the cardinality of input data and also increase the volume of data to Kafka i.e. stream more events per second to Kafka, we noticed that the Flink Job throws the following errors:

1. GC Overlimit Exceeded
2. Java Heap memory Out of Space- Error.

We tried running flink using Kubernetes Cluster and flink on YARN. In both cases, as the volume of data increased, we saw the above errors.
We provided 2 task managers 10 gb each and 1 gb for the job manager. The Checkpoint interval we have for our flink job is 3 minutes. I am aware that there has been a bug filed in the Flink- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20945.
Please let me know, if there is a way to solve this issue.